# How can I calculate $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\arctan(x)-\arcsin(x)}{x^3}$ without L'Hôpital?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\arctan(x)-\arcsin(x)}{x^3}$$

I am new in area of limits could you help me about that

Comment: If you were new to limits, you wouldn't have been given this problem.

Comment: Have you tried the Taylor expansions of $\arctan$ and $\arcsin$ around $x=0$?

Comment: Unless *specifically* asked to use Taylor expansions, to practice for example, I can't understand why Taylor expansions would be allowed where l'Hospital isn't.

Comment: If $\arcsin x = t$ then $\sin t = x$ and $\tan t = x/\sqrt{1 - x^{2}}$ so that $t = \arctan (x/\sqrt{1 - x^{2}})$ and then use $\arctan a - \arctan b = \arctan ((a - b)/(1 + ab))$. With some algebraic simplification it is easily seen that the limit is $-1/2$. No use of L'Hospital or Taylor's series is required.

Comment: @ Paramanand Singh: Your idea of expressing both in terms of arctan instead of mine which uses arcsin might be easier. In either case, I think you need $\sin(x)/x \to 1$.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to do this a different way
than just looking at the
power series,
which would make it trivial.

Start with
$\arctan(x)
=\arcsin(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}})
$
so that
$s(x)
=\arctan(x)-\arcsin(x)
=\arcsin(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}})-\arcsin(x)
$.

Then use
$\arcsin(a)-\arcsin(b)
=\arcsin(a\sqrt{1-b^2}-b\sqrt{1-a^2})
$
with
$a=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}
$
and
$b=x
$.

Note:
I got both these identities
from the Wikipedia articles
on inverse trig identities and functions.

Then
$1-a^2
=1-\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}
=\frac{1}{1+x^2}
$
so that

$\begin{array}\\
s(x)
&=\arcsin(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\sqrt{1-x^2}-x\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}})\\
&=\arcsin(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}(\sqrt{1-x^2}-1))\\
&=\arcsin(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}(\dfrac{-x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}+1}))\\
&=\arcsin(\frac{-x^3}{\sqrt{1+x^2}(\sqrt{1-x^2}+1)})\\
\end{array}
$

Since
$\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\sin(x)}{x}
=1
$
(this is the only
trig limit we need to know),
and
$\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\frac{-x^3}{\sqrt{1+x^2}(\sqrt{1-x^2}+1)}}{x^3}
=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{-1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}(\sqrt{1-x^2}+1)}
=-\frac12
$,
we get
$\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{s(x)}{x^3}
=-\dfrac12
$.

Comment: Simple and beautiful. +1 I had given same approach in comment to OP's question before looking at your answer.

Answer (score 1):

It *is* possible to compute the limit with using either L'Hopital's rule or Taylor series.  You just need to know that

$$\arctan x=\int_0^x{1\over1+t^2}dt\quad\text{and}\quad\arcsin x=\int_0^x{1\over\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt$$

Then, using some algebraic manipulations and a change of variable, we have

$$\begin{align}
{\arctan x-\arcsin x\over x^3}
&={1\over x^3}\int_0^x\left({1\over1+t^2}-{1\over\sqrt{1-t^2}} \right)dt\\
&={1\over x^3}\int_0^x{\sqrt{1-t^2}-(1+t^2)\over(1+t^2)\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt\\
&={1\over x^3}\int_0^x{1-t^2-(1+t^2)^2\over(1+t^2)\sqrt{1-t^2}(\sqrt{1-t^2}+(1+t^2))}dt\\
&={1\over x^3}\int_0^x{-3t^2-t^4\over(1+t^2)\sqrt{1-t^2}(\sqrt{1-t^2}+(1+t^2))}dt\\
&=-\int_0^13u^2{1+{1\over3}(xu)^2\over(1+(xu)^2)\sqrt{1-(xu)^2}(\sqrt{1-(xu)^2}+(1+(xu)^2))}du
\end{align}$$

To finish things off, it suffices to note that, for $0\le u\le1$,

$${1\over(1+x^2)(1+(1+x^2)) }\le{1+{1\over3}(xu)^2\over(1+(xu)^2)\sqrt{1-(xu)^2}(\sqrt{1-(xu)^2}+(1+(xu)^2))}\le {1+{1\over3}x^3\over\sqrt{1-x^2}(\sqrt{1-x^2}+1)}$$

and both bounds tend to $1\over2$ as $x\to0$. Thus, by the Squeeze Theorem, we arrive at

$$\lim_{x\to0}{\arctan x-\arcsin x\over x^3}=-{1\over2}\int_0^13u^2\,du=-{1\over2}$$

Comment: Very nice idea, using the integral representation.